# Gwan dies every day and consume a lot of ressources

Tags: vmware, g-wan

I would like to use Gwan for my rest webservices. It seems great, so I have installed it on a VMWare VM, on debian squeeeze. 
I have written a C webservice, it works perfectly.

The problem is that Gwan consumes always more and more ressources (the webservice is only use by me, and I do one or two hello world requests by day currently).
And then, it dies. 
Example, here : it started june 7th at 2pm, and died the day after at midnight. (not the full moon).

Here is the log file for the june 8th : http://pastebin.com/S8hFFPBu

Here is the head of the log file : http://pastebin.com/5eSEV4Wt

At start, it consume 2Mo of ram, at the end 73...

If someone have a clue on this, it would be great !

Thank you

Comment: Please post source code of the used servlets/handler/maintainence script/... if you want someone to help you with this. It's very possible (and probable) that your code is leaking memory, and not GWAN itself.

Comment: I doubt it. This happens to me as well as other people I know and is an issue. A friend told me to run it in a bash while loop without the daemon, as the daemon can die and not restart and that has helped but I've still seen G-WAN go and use 100% CPU on 1 core at times and there's some issues here.

Comment: G-WAN by itself won't enlarge memory usage as its default setup covers much larger needs than for mere tests. I noted that, *in contrast with your claims*, **you are running a script called nadra_hw.c** and this is the only way to leak memory. Also, when you change the question so radically, this is no longer the question that was answered - better create a new question than making the answer become irrelevant...

Comment: I got exactly the same problem while running Gwan on my virtualbox! Hope Gwan team could solve it on the coming release version!

Answer (score 0):

> G-WAN dies.

Duplicate of many other questions (almost all of them created by first-time stackoverflow users), look for: "`g-wan hypervisor`"

In addition, if your goal is really to resolve your problem, you could go as far as to read the [G-WAN FAQ *dedicated* to hypervisors](http://gwan.ch/faq#hypervisors).

Again, it is highly recommended to be using G-WAN without any hypervisor (here VMware), this will give G-WAN more than your paltry single CPU Core.

You could also leave more than `36.65 MiB free on a total of 370.88 MiB` for G-WAN (1 GB RAM should be made available for your virtual machine as Linux alone will take most of your 370 MiB... leading to a quasi-certain OOM "Out-Of-Memory" kill-switch).

---

UPDATE

That new problem for 4-years old code that worked fine so far is a platform issue, for which we have found a workaround, to be published with the next release in a few weeks.